# Delete edges with no faces

Tags: edges, knife-tool

There are edges in my object that are connected to a vertex, but have no face connected to them. I've tried to select "loose parts", but it doesn't find these edges. I've also tried "similar traits" with no luck. These edges are creating trouble, and there are hundreds of them. How can I select and delete them?

[image: Edges with no attached face - see white selected edge as an example.]

Answer (score 5):

In <kbd>2</kbd> *Edge Selection Mode*, select one such edge, then <kbd>⬆ Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> *Select Similar*, by <kbd>A</kbd> *Amount of Faces Around an Edge*, then <kbd>X</kbd> Delete <kbd>E</kbd> Edges.

[image]

Comment: Yep, that's probably the better less unnecessarily complicated way to do this compared to the way I do it. :D I always assumed this wouldn't work in cases like [this](https://imgur.com/LWjqWuo), but never tested it until now. Apparently it works fine. I guess I had different understanding of what is "faces around an edge".

Comment: @MartynasŽiemys This behavior is consistent with *Edge Neighbors* node and the number of unique faces when traversing using Bmesh loop's [`link_loop_radial_next`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bmesh.types.html#bmesh.types.BMLoop.link_loop_radial_next).

Answer (score 4):

Go to edit mode, select all (<kbd>a</kbd>), switch to face selection mode with <kbd>3</kbd>, switch to edge selection mode with <kbd>2</kbd>, invert selection with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>, hit <kbd>x</kbd> followed by <kbd>e</kbd> to delete edges.

This works because you are converting selection to faces and since those loose edges do not belong to faces, when selection of all faces is converted back to edge selection, the loose edges remain unselected.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution, although in your question you said you already tried "similar traits" (I guess you mean *Select All by Trait*):

Make sure you are in *Edge Select* mode by pressing <kbd>2</kbd> in the viewport (or *Vertex Select* with <kbd>1</kbd>, just not *Face Select*). Then choose *Select* > *Select All by Trait* > *Non-Manifold*. Now you can press <kbd>X</kbd> then <kbd>E</kbd> to delete the edges.

Comment: We need more answers :D One thing worries me, though, 3 people decided the question is worth an answer, and yet the question has only one upvote… 

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Yeah, I'm sorry, I seldomly vote on questions, neither up nor down. But I think this question leaves room for speculation and also draws opinion-based answers. For example, I would prefer my solution over yours, since I do not have to select anything beforehand. However, in the case which Martynas mentions in the comments under your answer, my solution would not work because the single faces would be selected as non-manifold as well. And we don't know how the rest of the mesh in question looks like. Martynas' answer is probably the one working best in most cases.

Comment: :D That's true. Python and Geometry Nodes answers are still missing.